# Add a loading gif when element fades out and remove it when new element fades in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this pagination set up so that when users click on the next arrow (`.paging-navigation a`), the current set of blog posts fade out and the new set fades in. Sometimes there is a delay while the new set loads in and I want to insert a loading gif there so users know nothing went wrong.

Here is how I have it set up:

```
$('#article-list').on('click', '.paging-navigation a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#news').offset().top - 60
    }, 500);
    $('#article-list').fadeOut(500, function(){

        // I would like to put in the animation gif here
           and fade it away when the new set of posts
           fade in.

        $(this).load(link + ' #article-list', function() {
            $(this).find('#article-list > *').unwrap().end().fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="news">
    <div id="article-list">
        <img class="loading-list" src="loading.gif" style="display:none">

        (blog posts here)

        <div class="paging-navigation">
            <div class="nav-previous">
                <a href="#">Prev</a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-next">
                <a href="#">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried showing/hiding the `.loading-list` img like this but it didn't work:

```
$('#article-list').on('click', '.paging-navigation a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#news').offset().top - 60
    }, 500);
    $('#article-list').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $('.loading-list').show();                                  <// added
        $(this).load(link + ' #article-list', function() {
            $(this).find('#article-list > *').unwrap().end().fadeIn(500);
        });
        $('.loading-list').hide();                                  <// added
    });
});
```

Can someone help me out?

Also, while the first set of posts fade out and the new posts are getting ready to load in, the height of the container div reduces suddenly to account for the lack of content and then the height shifts back when the new posts fade in. Is there any way to make the height of the div transition smoother?

Edit: CSS for `#article-list`

```
#news #article-list {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: If possible , can post `a` element included at `html` ? Thanks

Comment: `a` element? Do you mean wrap the `img` tag?

Comment: `.paging-navigation` , `.paging-navigation a` elements (html) not appear included at OP ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that. I included it.

Comment: Sorry again. Included it. It's the wrapper for everything.

Comment: please paste your css for #article-list

Comment: @ProllyGeek Sure, I added it in. It's not much.

Comment: fadeIn() also accepts an additional function argument (just like fadeOut()). You could hide your loading image like that. In other words, add a function to ```fadeIn(500, function () { $('.loading-list').hide();  });``` instead of after the call load.

Comment: I think what you need is to think a little more about how you're ordering things and using the callback functions for facdIn/facdOut/load. Can you describe a little more the order of things that you want to happen? Please be specific about things happening at the start of a fadeIn/fadeOut, or the end of a fadeIn/fadeOut.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="news">
<img class="loading-list" src="loading.gif" style="display:none">
    <div id="article-list">


        (blog posts here)

        <div class="paging-navigation">
            <div class="nav-previous">
                <a href="#">Prev</a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-next">
                <a href="#">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('#article-list').on('click', '.paging-navigation a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#news').offset().top - 60
    }, 500);
    $('#article-list').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $('.loading-list')[0].show();                                  <// added
        $(this).load(link + ' #article-list', function() {
            $(this).find('#article-list > *').unwrap().end().fadeIn(500);
        });
        $('.loading-list')[0].hide();                                  <// added
    });
});
```

this would work as long as you remove image a step up , you cant hide a parent and keep the child visible.

Edit:
selecting class will return a node list , so have to specify element,or use loading -list as id instead of class.

Edit (2)

Actually i dont know what is wrong with your source code , but jquery hide and show doesnt work for me.

However this worked :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("loading-list")[0].style.display="block";
```

so new code should be:

```
$('#article-list').on('click', '.paging-navigation a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#news').offset().top - 60
    }, 500);
    $('#article-list').fadeOut(500, function(){
         document.getElementsByClassName("loading-list")[0].style.display="block";;                                  <// added
        $(this).load(link + ' #article-list', function() {
            $(this).find('#article-list > *').unwrap().end().fadeIn(500);
        });
         document.getElementsByClassName("loading-list")[0].style.display="none";;                                  <// added
    });
});
```

Comment: @J82 are you sure you embedded the code , cause the image still display none after clicking arrow !

Comment: @J82 ohh you are selecting a class , this gonna return node list will edit code sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated

Try

v3

```
$('#article-list')
.on('click', '.paging-navigation a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#news').offset().top - 60
    }, 500, "linear");
    $('#article-list *:not(img.loading-list)')
    .fadeOut({
        duration: 500,
        start: function (promise) {
            $("img.loading-list")
                .fadeIn(0); 
        }
    }).promise().done(function(el) {
        $(el).siblings("img.loading-list")
        .fadeOut(1500, function() {
           // substituted `e.target` for `this`
           $(e.target).load(link + ' #article-list', function() {
            $('#article-list *:not(img.loading-list)')
                .fadeIn(500);
           });
        })
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/7mvrdzcj/

Comment: I don't see a loading gif in your fiddle. Is it because it's too fast?

Comment: Tried clicking "Prev" , "Next" ?

Comment: That didn't work either. When I click on a navigation arrow, the loading gif pops up and then fades away while shrinking. The new posts don't show up, either.

Comment: See updated post. Changed `.show()` / `.hide()` to `.fadeIn()` / `.fadeOut()` , adjusted selector for `.load()`

Comment: It's still not working. The loader still goes away too fast and when I'm on the second set of posts and click the left arrow, the same set of posts remain.

Comment: Sorry, that one doesn't work either. When I click the navigation button, the loader comes out, and when it goes away, the same set of posts fade in but with the titles not hidden.

Comment: See updated post. "Prev" and "Next" only contain `#` at `href` attribute , no `url` to pass to `.load()` ? Substituted `e.target` for `this` at .load()`

Comment: Yeah, that one behaved the exact same way as the last one. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You are welcome. Thank you . "Prev" and "Next" only contain `#` at `href` attribute , not other `url` to pass to .load() ? `.load()` is receiving this value as `url` with current piece (`.load(link + ' #article-list'`) - `# #article-list` - essentially loading same `div` . Perhaps not certain what content to be loaded , and where to load content ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `$('.loading-list').hide()` into the callback function of the `.load()`.

```
$('#article-list').on('click', '.paging-navigation a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#news').offset().top - 60
    }, 500);
    $('#article-list').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('.loading-list').show();
        $(this).load(link + ' #article-list', function () {
            $('.loading-list').hide(); //moved here
            $(this).find('#article-list > *').unwrap().end().fadeIn(500);
        });
        //from here
    });
});
```

So you show the gif, start loading the new content, then when the content is done loading, the callback function hides the gif and fades in the new content.

As for the height, you can use CSS `transition` to smooth out the changes. But since you can't transition to and from `height: auto`, you need a workaround. Something like:

CSS:

```
#article-list {
    min-height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: min-height 0.5s;
    transition: min-height 0.5s;
}
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$('#article-list').on('click', '.paging-navigation a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#news').offset().top - 60
    }, 500);
    $('#article-list').css('min-height', 400); //change min-height here
    $('#article-list').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('.loading-list').show();
        $(this).load(link + ' #article-list', function () {
            $('.loading-list').hide();
            $(this).find('#article-list > *').unwrap().end().fadeIn(500);
            $('#article-list').css('min-height', 0); //change min-height here
        });
    });
});
```

So right before you start to fade out the old content, you set the `min-height`, so the div doesn't collapse. When right after the new content starts to fade in, so it's already filling some of the div's height, you set the `min-height` back to 0, allowing the transition to smoothly shrink the div to the new content's height.

Let me know if something doesn't work, since it's a little hard for me to test this code.

Comment: I tried your code, but it looks like now the loading gif comes up but doesn't go away, nor do the new posts show up. Also, I see the CSS changes but no smooth transition.